# After that it should display the count and the total sum of the numbers entered. It adds the negative numbers for some reason. 0 to end

Tags: java, calculation

Hi I'm pretty new to Java.
I've got this program i'm trying to finish. But for some reason it doesn't subtract the negative numbers from the sum. It only adds them.
here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       double count = 0;
       double sum = 0;
       while (true) {

           System.out.println("Give a number: ");
           int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

           if (number == 0) {break;}
           if (number > 0) {count = count + 1;}
           if (number < 0) {count = count + 1;}
           if (number < 0) {sum = sum - number;}
           if (number > 0) {sum = sum + number;}
           if (number > 0 && number < 0) {continue;}




       }
        System.out.println("The total count is: " + count);
        System.out.println("The sum of the count is: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if you pass a negative number like `-1` you will get `sum = sum - (-1)` which becomes `sum = sum + 1`.

You just need to change:

```
if (number < 0) {sum = sum - number;}
```

To:

```
if (number < 0) {sum = sum + number;}
```

Also you can shorten the if-else conditions like this:

```
if (number == 0) {
    break;
} else {
    count++;
    sum += number;
}
```